# How to use “Application.Current.Terminate” using cpp on WP8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, terminate

I am writing a C++ DirectX application without XAML for Windows Phone 8.
I handled the back key because I want to close the app on manual,
but I find no API for cpp.

C# has official API `System.Windows.Application.Current.Terminate()`,
but cpp has no namespace `System::Windows::Application`.

I've search a lot but I can only find the C# method.
I've tried `Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Close();`
It can close app, but it causes a `Platform::COMException`, and it can't be resolved by try-catch.

**////////////////////update 1/////////////**

well i find

```
int b = 0.1*10 - 1;
int a = 1/ b;
```

app will exit too.
so `Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Close();` is not a way for close.
maybe it is just a crash.

**////////////////////update 2/////////////**

I find a API

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Exit();
```

but doc says that

> "Shuts down the app. Do not use this method to shut down an app outside of testing or debugging scenarios."

so I think it will not pass the test.

**////////////////////update 3/////////////**

if use 
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Exit();
to close app. and then if i click the icon to restart the app. it will cost a very very very long time to start.
may be Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Exit() close some system service.
but if use exception to close app it will not cost a long time to start.

**////////////////////update 4/////////////**

if use 
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Exit();
in simulator it can not restart app by click icon again

Comment: you can't. why do you want your app to terminate?

Comment: when user press back key, I popup a dialog to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to exit the app is break out of the `CoreApplication::Run` while() loop.

For instance for the default template cube DirectX sample app, all you need to do is set `m_windowClosed` member variable to true.

So if you want the app to end if you tap the screen, do...

```
void PhoneDirect3DApp1::OnPointerPressed(CoreWindow^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    m_windowClosed = true;
}
```

However as the comments say you must take care to handle the back button appropriately or else you'll fail cert.

Comment: it is useful.thanks very very much.
I search in MSDN for lots of time to terminate app, but forget to read the code carefully.

very very thanks.